# Save the value of checked checkbox as 1

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I save the value of checked checkbox as 1 and unchecked as 0, I'm using boolean on my model.

```
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input name="vat" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"  [(ngModel)]="VatExempt">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">VAT EXEMPT &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>  <div class="row pl-4 font-italic">(Check if PEZA member)</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter (other variable)

```
get VatExemptInt(){
  return VatExempt?1:0
}
```

By the way, it's a common use camel-case to name the variables (better vatExempt, than VatExempt)